# How to identify the custom-element that started a core-ajax call (from the core-ajax response)

Tags: javascript, ajax, polymer

I'm using Polymer to generate a list o custom elements (post-card).
Inside each custom element there is a thumbnail of an image that will expand and show the "original image" when clicked.
The "original image" link is obtained from a response to an ajax call to imgur API (with a core-ajax component).

I tried this two routes... but I'm still unsure about the best solution:

**1. Using a core-ajax component inside each post-card element.**

This solution seems to work but it's far from elegant in my opinion.

**2. Using a single core-ajax component to manage every API request.**

*Post-list.html*

```
<core-ajax 
  url="{{imgur_url}}"
  handleAs="json"
  on-core-response="{{handleResponse}}">
</core-ajax>

<template repeat="{{post, postIndex in posts}}">
    <post-card post={{post}} id={{postIndex}} on-img-tap={{imgurRequest}}>
</template>
```

The main problem I'm facing with this solution is that when I get the response back from core-ajax I'm not able to identify the custom element (post-card) which sent the request.

I thought about creating a new custom element extending core-ajax, allowing me to pass as a parameter (and get it back in the response) the id of the post-card which sent the request... but I think there must be a  simpler solution, right?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you have something like `this.$.ajaxId.go();` in your `imgurRequest` function (regarding your second solution). What you could do is sending the `postIndex` through ajax parameters. Your `imgurRequest` would look somewhat like this:

```
imgurRequest: function(e, detail, sender) {
  var postIndex = e.target.templateInstance.model.postIndex;
  // Set a property (to postIndex) which is bound to ajax parameter list here ...
  this.$.ajaxId.go();
}
```

This way you can distinguish between your post cards while using the same function and same core-ajax element. The server should of course send the received id back to client.

Comment: This is exactly what i wanted to do, but I didn't know that it is possible to assign a parameter to the code-ajax and get it back in the response... I thought it was just a parameter consumed by the server.
But I was wrong, I can get it in the response if I do this in core-ajax:

`params='{"postId": "{{postId}}"}'`

Thank you.